# Certificate invalid

Tags: iphone, openssl, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am trying this for the past week. I dont know where I am going wrong. I want to setup a MDM server that dont have static IP. I have a DNS resolvable name for the server. I have the identity.key and identity.csr for which I created the MDM vendor certificate. I wrote a following .bat file to generate other certificates

```
echo 1. Creating Certificate Authority (CA)
echo For 'Common Name' enter something like 'MDM Test CA
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout cakey.key -out cacert.crt -days 365

echo 2. Creating the Web Server private key and certificate request
echo  For 'Common Name' enter your server's DNS Name
openssl genrsa 2048 > server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr 

echo 3. Signing the server key with the CA. You'll the CA passphrase from step 1.
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA cacert.crt -CAkey cakey.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -extfile .\server.cnf -extensions ssl_server

echo 4. Signing the identity key with the CA. You'll the CA passphrase from step 1.
echo Give it a passphrase. You'll need to include that in the IPCU profile
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in identity.csr -CA cacert.crt -CAkey cakey.key -CAcreateserial -out identity.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out identity.p12 -inkey identity.key -in identity.crt -certfile cacert.crt
```

I used the identity.p12 file and created a *encoded plist* file for which push notification certificate is created. I also create a MDM profile in IPCU with the identity.p12 file. When I try to install the MDM profile, the mobile console says "Certificate in the server is invalid" and in the server it says SSL handshake failed and the server gets hanged.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Anand - did Apple sign the server's certificate? All these things are part of Apple's PKI. To access Apple's PKI and signing services, you need a developer account. Through your developer account, you submit signing requests.

Comment: I have the enterprise developer account and also have the MDM vendor certificae, Push-Notification certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In server.cnf -> subjectAltName I gave a parameter named DNS with DNS resolvable name and removed the IP. Now it is working fine.